# Security practice for making an external API calls with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-oauth

I tested in console and don't have access to these globals but curious if this is NOT ok to do in Meteor:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Twit = Meteor.npmRequire('twit')
    T = new Twit({
        consumer_key:         'cYiYGQ0BsN4DCM2'
      , consumer_secret:      'uU6g0RqcDkkHwasaibQ5zi6Zpgtb'
      , access_token:         '324050hbjhVvdgi0xEUHKreca9u7dTo'
      , access_token_secret:  'gCNBxu3NAQ9dNbhbvU6KwX'
    });
  });
```

If this is NOT best practice, please provide an answer which would still allow me to access the variable 'T' in a Meteor.methods call. Thanks!

Comment: It is on server -- so which console are you trying it on? Browser?

Comment: Correct, and they are not accessible (which is good) so I'm just curious if this is an ok practice with security in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {...}
```

guards against execution on the client side, however unless the file resides in the `/server` directory is it still made available to the client although not executed.   This means that anybody who is browsing the javascript downloaded from your server **can observe your keys** !!!

Im sure you would agrree with that being bad.

First of all it is not recommended that you put your keys into source code (for many reasons too long to list here), but if you do (as a quick hack) place the file with the keys in the `/server` directory so they are not observable to the world.

Read about `Meteor.settings` for how to avoid having your keys in the code and managed externally in a file separate from the source.

With Meteor.setting your code would be looking something like;

`file: $(projecthome)/server/twitter.js:`

```
   Meteor.startup(function () {
     Twit = Meteor.npmRequire('twit')
     T = new Twit({
         consumer_key:         Meteor.settings.TWIT.key
       , consumer_secret:      Meteor.settings.TWIT.secret
       , access_token:         Meteor.settings.TWIT.token
       , access_token_secret:  Meteor.settings.TWIT.token_secret
     });
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed response which also points me in a direction to learn more. Much appreciated.